# Не работает Inline кнопка aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```py
inline_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Первая кнопка!', callback_data='button1')
inline_kb1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(inline_btn_1)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("1")
    await Form.number.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.number)
async def process_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer(f"inline",reply_markup=inline_kb1)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'button1')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Нажата первая кнопка!')
```

После нажатия на `Первая кнопка!` ничего не происходит. Почему так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ от ChatGPT. Рабочий

```
# Обработчик команды /start
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    # Создаем inline клавиатуру с кнопкой "Нажмите на меня"
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button = InlineKeyboardButton("Нажмите на меня", callback_data='press_button')
    keyboard.add(button)

    # Отправляем пользователю сообщение с кнопкой
    await message.answer("Привет! Нажмите на кнопку:", reply_markup=keyboard)

# Обработчик нажатия на inline кнопку
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'press_button')
async def process_button_click(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    # Отправляем пользователю сообщение "1" без отображения на экране
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.message.chat.id, "1")
```